# Dealing with whitespace in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file and one of the tables is named "FOOD NAME." I'm trying to save it in a DataFrame but I am receiving a syntax error. Is there any way on how to do it?

```py
import pandas
data_frame = pandas.read_csv('foods.csv')
filter_data = data_frame[(data_frame.['FOOD NAME'] == 'Vegetables')]
print(filter_data.to_string())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.` from select column:

```
filter_data = data_frame[(data_frame['FOOD NAME'] == 'Vegetables')]
                                  ^^^^
```